# Yii2 Multiple input mask on a page with same ID

Tags: yii2, input-mask

```
<?php
        echo $form->field($fModel, 'cell_phone')
            ->widget(\yii\widgets\MaskedInput::className(),['mask' => '(999)999-9999'])
           ->textInput(['placeholder' => 'Phone'])->label(false);
 ?>
```

I have 2 tab with same form with one extra field on second. Issue is that it showing masked input on one tab form and not on second. Anything I am doing wrong. They have same input name/id   but FORM ID is different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use another id for second field both for widget and text input. Try this:

```
<?= $form->field($fModel, 'cell_phone')
    ->widget(\yii\widgets\MaskedInput::className(), ['options' => ['id' => 'another-id'], 'mask' => '(299)999-9999'])
    ->textInput(['id' => 'another-id', 'placeholder' => 'Phone'])->label(false);
?>
```

Comment: thanks it working. but wondering why we need ID twice in widget as well textinput.

Comment: Because widget first register script `jQuery("#input-id").inputmask(..)`. Default #input-id is created from model and attribute before render textInput.